# Rendering partial view with model and property set at instantiation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

par I'm trying to call a Partial view, passing in a new model, setting a property value on the instantiate.

The below code errors as follows: 'CS1525: Invalid expression term '{''

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/_ContactUs.cshtml", new ContactUsModel({ThankYouPage = 555}))
```

However if I replace it with the below, the view renders without error:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/_ContactUs.cshtml", new ContactUsModel())
```

Can anyone spot what my issue?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your syntax is wrong if you want to set property during instantiate activity you have to do this that way:

```
new ContactUsModel() { ThankYouPage = 555 }
```

or

```
new ContactUsModel { ThankYouPage = 555 }
```